# Why isn't indexTZ() working and changing the time?

Tags: r, datetime, timezone, xts, posixct

I have an xts object with timezone in "GMT", from what I've seen throughout this website I can use `indexTZ()` to change the time zone. I have tried every trick possible, first specifying "GMT" then changing it to "IST". Specifying "IST" when I first convert the timestamps to Date Time format: `DF$DateTime= as.POSIXct(DF$DateTime/(10^9), origin="1970-01-01", tz = "IST")` but it still gives me time in "GMT". Basically, nothing happens.

```
> head(auro)
                               MP       avgVWAP TradePressure Modify
2015-11-30 03:45:01  0.0000000000  0.0000117703            37    107
2015-11-30 03:45:02  0.0016475976  0.0004038842            11     30
2015-11-30 03:45:03  0.0007009310  0.0013219980            13     34
2015-11-30 03:45:04 -0.0003656419 -0.0002547382            11      0
2015-11-30 03:45:05 -0.0004572404 -0.0003604543             4      0
2015-11-30 03:45:06  0.0005486634  0.0003343666             7    -14
Warning message:
timezone of object (GMT) is different than current timezone (IST). 
> indexTZ(auro)<- "IST"
> head(auro)
                               MP       avgVWAP TradePressure Modify
2015-11-30 03:45:01  0.0000000000  0.0000117703            37    107
2015-11-30 03:45:02  0.0016475976  0.0004038842            11     30
2015-11-30 03:45:03  0.0007009310  0.0013219980            13     34
2015-11-30 03:45:04 -0.0003656419 -0.0002547382            11      0
2015-11-30 03:45:05 -0.0004572404 -0.0003604543             4      0
2015-11-30 03:45:06  0.0005486634  0.0003343666             7    -14
> indexTZ(auro)<- "UTC"
> head(auro)
                               MP       avgVWAP TradePressure Modify
2015-11-30 03:45:01  0.0000000000  0.0000117703            37    107
2015-11-30 03:45:02  0.0016475976  0.0004038842            11     30
2015-11-30 03:45:03  0.0007009310  0.0013219980            13     34
2015-11-30 03:45:04 -0.0003656419 -0.0002547382            11      0
2015-11-30 03:45:05 -0.0004572404 -0.0003604543             4      0
2015-11-30 03:45:06  0.0005486634  0.0003343666             7    -14
Warning message:
timezone of object (UTC) is different than current timezone (IST).
```

I noticed there is a disconnect between my time and time zone. Time is in "GMT" but the time zone displayed is in "IST"

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2016-03-23 06:49:00.816 IST"
```

So I thought changing system time zone first might help, but it doesn't. Again, nothing happens.

```
> Sys.setenv(TZ = "GMT")
> Sys.time()
[1] "2016-03-23 06:51:31.044 GMT"
> indexTZ(auro)<- "IST"
> head(auro)
                               MP       avgVWAP TradePressure Modify
2015-11-30 03:45:01  0.0000000000  0.0000117703            37    107
2015-11-30 03:45:02  0.0016475976  0.0004038842            11     30
2015-11-30 03:45:03  0.0007009310  0.0013219980            13     34
2015-11-30 03:45:04 -0.0003656419 -0.0002547382            11      0
2015-11-30 03:45:05 -0.0004572404 -0.0003604543             4      0
2015-11-30 03:45:06  0.0005486634  0.0003343666             7    -14
Warning message:
timezone of object (IST) is different than current timezone (GMT).
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Does `indexTZ()` or `Sys.setenv()` just change timezone and not calibrate time to the time zone specified?

If thats the case then, what can I do to change the time and time zone of my xts object?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this solves your problem, but IST does not seem to be a timezone that is supported by R. You could try to pick a suitable name of the timezone from the output of `OlsonNames()`.

Comment: @RHertel I dont think you're right 
`> Sys.time()
[1] "2016-03-23 13:15:32.470 IST"`
Once, I restarted R, the disconnect between the time and time zone went away. But problem still persists

Comment: IST -- Indian Standard Time

Comment: IST is also used for [Israel Standard Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist-israel). This ambiguity might be a reason why it is not considered as a suitable value in R. As stated in `?Sys.timezone`: "*Time zones are a system-specific topic*". I suspect that with `Sys.time()` you are simply retrieving the time zone of your OS; which may or may not be compatible with time zones used by R.

Comment: @RHertel Interesting, never came to my mind. That answers my question. Weird that it doesn't throw an error when it doesn't recognize it. Ive been using "IST" everywhere.

Comment: Indian Standard Time -- "Asia/Kolkata"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments, "IST" is not a valid timezone. It is best to specify timezones in Country/City format. If you do that, the printed times will be updated.

```
require(xts)
Lines <- "datetime,MP,avgVWAP,TradePressure,Modify
2015-11-30 03:45:01,0.0000000000,0.0000117703,37,107
2015-11-30 03:45:02,0.0016475976,0.0004038842,11,30
2015-11-30 03:45:03,0.0007009310,0.0013219980,13,34
2015-11-30 03:45:04,-0.0003656419,-0.0002547382,11,0
2015-11-30 03:45:05,-0.0004572404,-0.0003604543,4,0
2015-11-30 03:45:06,0.0005486634,0.0003343666,7,-14"
x <- as.xts(read.zoo(text=Lines,FUN=as.POSIXct,tz="GMT",header=TRUE,sep=","))
x
#                                MP       avgVWAP TradePressure Modify
# 2015-11-30 03:45:01  0.0000000000  0.0000117703            37    107
# 2015-11-30 03:45:02  0.0016475976  0.0004038842            11     30
# 2015-11-30 03:45:03  0.0007009310  0.0013219980            13     34
# 2015-11-30 03:45:04 -0.0003656419 -0.0002547382            11      0
# 2015-11-30 03:45:05 -0.0004572404 -0.0003604543             4      0
# 2015-11-30 03:45:06  0.0005486634  0.0003343666             7    -14
indexTZ(x) <- "Asia/Kolkata"
x
#                               MP       avgVWAP TradePressure Modify
# 2015-11-30 09:15:01  0.0000000000  0.0000117703            37    107
# 2015-11-30 09:15:02  0.0016475976  0.0004038842            11     30
# 2015-11-30 09:15:03  0.0007009310  0.0013219980            13     34
# 2015-11-30 09:15:04 -0.0003656419 -0.0002547382            11      0
# 2015-11-30 09:15:05 -0.0004572404 -0.0003604543             4      0
# 2015-11-30 09:15:06  0.0005486634  0.0003343666             7    -14
```